# Can magnetization currents explain any arbitrary current distribution?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

Bouncing off of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355538/how-do-the-magnetic-fields-produced-by-permanent-magnets-and-moving-charges-diff), but trying to be a good bit more precise: given an arbitrary (bulk, but particularly line or surface) electric current distribution, is it possible to provide a magnetization field whose magnetization current will match the given distribution?

To expand a bit more on this, for any given magnetization field $\mathbf M(\mathbf r)$, regardless of whether it arises from microscopic loops of current or from fundamental magnetic dipoles coming from electronic or nuclear spins, the magnetic field it produces can be understood as coming exclusively from the [magnetization current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization#Magnetization_current) of the field, which is given by
$$
\mathbf J_\mathrm m = \nabla \times\mathbf M
$$
in bulk and
$$
\mathbf K_\mathrm m = \mathbf M \times \hat{\mathbf n}
$$
at surfaces, which shows that the magnetic field of any permanent magnet can also be produced with a suitable distribution of electric currents.

My question is the converse: if I have an arbitrary electric current distribution, can I find a magnetization field that will produce the same magnetic field? In bulk it's relatively easy (in static conditions $\mathbf J$ must obey $\nabla\cdot\mathbf J=0$, so there exists a 'vector potential' $\mathbf M$ such that $\mathbf J = \nabla \times\mathbf M$) but it's slightly less clear for surface currents and line electric circuits. For the latter I'm prepared to accept thin surfaces of high magnetization, so long as (i) they exist globally, and (ii) they don't have nontrivial bulk effects in the middle of the surface; for surface currents it's not fully clear to me that a curl-free field can exist in the interior of the surface with a fixed normal component (or, at least, which theorems guarantee its existence).

As a simple example of what I mean, consider the magnetic field produced by a thin disk of radius $R$ and thickness $a\ll R$ with uniform magnetization along the disk axis: i.e. the magnetic field produced by a uniform surface current along the thin cylindrical surface, which converges (as you make $a/R\to 0$ while keeping $aM=\mathrm{const}$) to the field of a circle of current. I'm mostly looking for models like this for arbitrary circuits.

So: is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If we work in the absence of magnetization, and we have some current $\mathbf{J}$ (with $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = 0$ and $\dot{\mathbf{J}}=\mathbf{0}$, and with $\mathbf{J}$ possibly being singular, that is, containg line currents and surface currents), then we know that there is  unique field $\mathbf{B}$ satisfying $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{J}$. Furthermore, this $\mathbf{B}$ is given by the Biot-Savart law. So basically your $\mathbf{M}$ should be the $\mathbf{B}$ sourced by your current. What is the additional issue I'm not understanding?

Comment: @NowIGet A method to get $\mathbf M$ from $\mathbf B$ (assuming vanishing free currents) would be sufficient. However, for line currents, I would expect that method to be undetermined given the non-uniqueness of spanning surfaces (or maybe you're forced onto a canonical spanning surface? if so, an explanation of how and why would be necessary) so a discussion of the relationship between the method and the choice of surface would be appropriate.

Comment: Oh you are right. There is no constraint that the magnetization is divergencless; that is the tricky part I missed. So it seems you can take the result you get from the Biot-Savart law and add the gradient of any function. So there exists solutions but they are not unique. Does that sound right?

Comment: @NowIGet, oh, I see what you meant. I'm not particularly sold on that particular solution, at least for line currents, because they involve some pretty hefty singularities (though arguably my $M\to\infty$ solution is equally troublesome) beyond the finite discontinuities needed for surface currents. But maybe adding a gradient can take away that singularity?

Comment: In §13.2.6 of Zangwill's *Modern Electrodynamics*, he makes basically the same point as @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs:  the transformation $\vec{M} \to \vec{M} + \nabla \Lambda$ leaves everything unchanged.  At the end of this (brief) section, Zangwill points to a reference with further discussion of this point, which might be of interest to you:  L.L. Hirst, "The microscopic magnetization:  Concept and application", *Rev. Mod. Phys.* **69**, 607 (1997).